# Is it possible to connect to Oracle DB from Node app in AWS Lambda without using Lambda Layers?

Tags: node.js, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-modules

I have been trying to set up a lambda that requires a connection to an Oracle database. I am not able to use lambda layers as I am configuring this lambda through a service catalog product that does not offer that functionality right now. Pretty much everything I am finding online about connecting to an Oracle DB from a Node lambda in AWS uses lambda layers. Is there some way to configure this or is using lambda layers the only way?

Comment: You have to bundle Oracle client with your lambda function then.

Comment: You need to install an Oracle driver somehow. Does this approach work with your constraint of not using layers? https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-java-oracle-starter-kit